# Qt event is not propagating from child to parent

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt6

I have created a small example to try and understand the event handing in Qt.
From the documentation and from what I understand is that when I install an event filter, when I click a widget the event will be sent to the associated `eventFilter`. Now, if I do not consume that event, **it should be propogated to the parent**. In my example below inside the `eventFilter` in `ChildWidget` I make a print statement when it is clicked, however I also have a return `False` meaning it should be then sent to the parent which is `MainWindow` which it should then call the `eventFilter` on the `MainWindow` which is not happening.

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFrame, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QPushButton
from PyQt6.QtCore import QEvent


class ChildWidget(QPushButton):
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress:
            print("Mouse click event handled in the child widget")
            return False
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


class MainWindow(QFrame):
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress:
            print("Mouse click event handled in the main window")
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.setWindowTitle("Event Propagation Example")
    main_window.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 200)

    child_widget = ChildWidget("Click me! I'm the child widget")

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(QLabel("Hello from the main window"))
    layout.addWidget(child_widget)

    main_window.setLayout(layout)

    child_widget.installEventFilter(child_widget)
    main_window.installEventFilter(main_window)

    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I was hoping someone can explain why my event is not being sent up to the parent despite not being consumed.

Comment: By returning false from the event filter you're telling Qt to continue with normal event processing -- that means calling the child's mouse press event handler.  If you want the event to pass to the parent then override `mousePressEvent` in `ChildWidget` and call `event.ignore()`.

Comment: @G.M. Why does calling `event.ignore()` work but returning False does not? I thought they would be similar given the API, https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#eventFilter

Comment: It makes little sense for an object to install an event-filter on *itself*. The main purpose of an event-filter is to allow one object to monitor the events of another. This is particularly useful when it's not possible to subclass the target object. If you already have a subclass, you can just directly override the appropriate event-handler. In your example, `child_widget` does not install an event-filter on `main_window`, so the latter will never see any events from the former. If you comment out the `child_widget.installEventFilter` line, your example will print nothing.

Comment: @G.M. Also when I add `event.ignore()` by itself, it only has the one print statement. However, if I define `mousePressEvent()` it will call the `mousePressEvent()` and call the parent `eventFilter`. Why is this happening? I thought it would be change the default return value of `moseuPressEvent()`or something similar, but the API says that it returns `void` so that cannot be the reason.

Comment: @ekhumoro My example was purely educational, I was just trying to study the event propagation behaviour, also my work does some fancy still with it which I am failing to understand so I was just trying to get my head around how events are passed around and the propogation relationship between parent-child.

Comment: @memelord23 Your example is completely broken, so it's the exact opposite of educational. As I said, `main_window.eventFilter` will never see any events from `child_widget`, because `child_widget` does not install an event-filter on `main_window`. You need to remove the current two install lines and replace them with `child_widget.installEventFilter(main_window)`.

Comment: @ekhumoro By doing that, isn't that just suggesting that `ChildWidget` is now responsible for determining which events `MainWindow` will use by the return True/False? The original idea behind my example was that the `QPushButton` gets clicked, intentionally ignores the mouse click event and allows it to propogate to its parent. I.e. the `ChildWidget` would return `False` and then I would have expected the same event object to be passed to the `eventFilter` on the `MainWindow`, is this not how events are moved from child -> parent for event propogation?

Comment: @memelord23 If you want to properly understand event propagation, you should override [`event`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#event) in both `MainWindow` and `ChildWidget`, and then return true or false as appropriate. An event-filter is the wrong tool for this job, since it merely *monitors* the events of another object. (See also: [The Event System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/eventsandfilters.html) in the Qt docs).